# how do I search an ebook in epub format on a Mac?

Tags: macbook, ebook, epub

I have purchased an e-book from ebooks.com in epub format.
I need to read it on a MAC, and I need to search for specific phrases.
Is this possible, and how?

Comment: https://pdf.wondershare.com/macos-10-14/epub-for-macos-10-14.html -> At least one of them should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The best EBook reader I know is
[calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/)
which is [available for macOS](https://calibre-ebook.com/download_osx).

Import the epub into calibre and start the viewer.
It has excellent search capabilities.